# Android JSON Data Posting results in IO Exception Always

Tags: java, php, android, json

I have a server and I use following Link to post data in my DB

http://URL.php?action=insert&vhc=vehiclenumber&mobile=mobilenumberoftheperson&time=currenttime

To keep record of vehicle entering time, Now I want to post same Data from Android for which I am using Following Code:

***Inside Button Goes this:***

```
 button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Data is tried!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    postData();
                }
            }).start();
        }
    });
```

And my PostData Function is defined below:

```
public void postData() {
    // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("url.php");

    try {
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("vhc", "ABC124"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("mobile", "089944440000"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("time", "2014-12-28 22:22:52"));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        message = e.getMessage();
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    } catch (IOException e) {
        message= e.getMessage();

        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    }
}
```

Now I tried to debug and found it failing at HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost); step and leads it to IOException, Please indicate my error to resolve the issue. Thanks!

Comment: http://URL.php is not a valid url. Post your logcat.

Comment: I just made this URL to show, actual one is like www.websiteServer.com/myDBname.php?action=insert&vhc=vehiclenumber etc

Comment: Use a async library such as retrofit. At the very least use async task do not create a thread for this.

Answer (score -1):

In you current solution you create a thread, but the thread execute you code sequentially and it does not wait for the response from your server. As a result your client get a null response.

Solution : you have to use AsyncTask for retrieve/send data from/to server. Execute data retrieve part in the doBackground method of AsyncTask. And get your response from the postExecute method. See details [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Comment: Thanks, I have used Async Call now, I do not face IOerror but even now data is not being sent. I cannot see my record being sent to the DB